# MixItUp 3 animations isn't working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

I updated my portfolio website and converted my MixItUp portfolio from 2 to 3. However, the animations are acting weird. Every time I click on a filter link, some of the portfolio projects fly up over the "Portfolio" title while fading in. I don't like the effects. I can tell that the animation is working when I adjusted the duration, however, I don't know how to fix the rest to make it looks normal like this demo:

https://www.kunkalabs.com/mixitup/

Here's where you can see where the animations are all wrong:

http://kikidesign.net/portfolio

My Javascript code is:

```
<script>
    var containerEl = document.querySelector('.mixitup-list');

    var mixer = mixitup(containerEl, { //MixItUp 3 options, 'item' matches the class in the PHP

        animation: {
        duration: 800,
        nudge: false,
        reverseOut: false,
        effects: "fade scale(0.41)"
    }


    });
</script>
```

It's located in footer.php.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the problem. It's the height. I specific the height of each portfolio piece to be 100% and thus, it messed up the animations.